# Eclipse 2019 12 lack of Tomcat 9.0 in Runtime Environment

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, servlets, runtime-environment

I need to develop simple servlet using Tomcat 9.0, but once I try to add it as my Runtime Environment it does not show on the list of available ones. I am using latest version of Eclipse, and I have installed JST Adapters, Java EE Developer Tools and Eclipse Tomcat Plugin 9.1.4. What do I do in order to be able to see and use tomcat 9.0?

The only answers to this question I found were that I'm possibly using old verion of IDE or lacking the plugins I installed already.

Does anybody know what could be the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

What could the problem be? The second one. You need the JST Server Adapter *Extensions* feature.